# SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '["1","3","66","68"]' for column 'infraction_id' at row 1

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am trying to save the entire data, but I need to array, and data format error occurs.

blade

```
@foreach($infractions as $infraction)
    <tr>
        <th>{{ $infraction->title }}</th>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="infraction_id[]" value="{{ $infraction->id }}" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-score="{{ $infraction->score }}">
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $inspection = new Inspection();
    $inspection->infraction_id = $request->infraction_id;
    $inspection->encouragement_id = 1;
    $inspection->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $inspection->requisition_id = $request->input('requisition_id');
    $inspection->save();
    $inspection->requisitions()->update(['status' => 1]);
    return redirect()->route('inspection-results.index');
}
```

I see this error

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer
>   value: '["1","3","66","68"]' for column 'infraction_id' at row 1 (SQL:
>   insert into `inspections` (`infraction_id`, `encouragement_id`,
>   `user_id`, `requisition_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values
>   (["1","3","66","68"], 1, 1, 1, 2018-11-08 10:40:45, 2018-11-08
>   10:40:45))

[image: array]

Comment: Iterate over `$request->infraction_id` with `foreach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are getting n array of values for `infraction_id` (when you define it in your HTML you use `name="infraction_id[]"`) You will need to add multiple records...

```
foreach ( $request->infraction_id as $infraction_id ) {
    $inspection = new Inspection();
    $inspection->infraction_id = (int)$infraction_id;
    $inspection->encouragement_id = 1;
    $inspection->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $inspection->requisition_id = $request->input('requisition_id');
    $inspection->save();
    $inspection->requisitions()->update(['status' => 1]);
}
return redirect()->route('inspection-results.index');
```

Comment: I get this error:
`SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '"66"' for column 'infraction_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `inspections` (`infraction_id`, `encouragement_id`, `user_id`, `requisition_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ("66", 1, 1, 1, 2018-11-08 11:17:48, 2018-11-08 11:17:48))`

Comment: thanks for answer only it save 1 checkbox but I want multi checkbox when checked the checkboxes.

Comment: Sorry - I had left the `return` inside the loop.  This (of course) would stop after the first item.  I've corrected my code.